# How to hook up observablecollection member to application resources (resx) file

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Hey guys first of all sorry for the bad explanation. My task is translation an application that i wrote not so long ago,generally nothing special.

But now i am at a stick point. One  function of my application is to save history. i have created a basic class for that purpose.

```
 public class GHistoryClass
    {
       public GHistoryClass(string act, string icop, string categ, string desc,)
        {
            this.m_Action = act;
            this.m_IconPath = icop;
            this.m_Description = desc;
            this.m_Category = categ;

        }
        public string m_Action { get; set; }
        public string m_Description { get; set; }
        public string m_Category { get; set; }
        public string m_IconPath { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm saving the history like `ObservableCollection` in the `IsolatedStorage`.
When the language is changed i wanna to translate the history.

I can not figure it out, for example how to hook up `m_Action` to `localized resourses`.

Any ideas will be most appreciated.

**EDIT**

what i think should do the trick is to save the name of the `AppResources` property name as string
so `m_Action = "AppResources.firstaction"` then my idea is to cast it as `PropertyPath`.
Is this a good idea, how can i convert `string` to `object` name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a resource (resx) file to your project, you end up with a generated property for each resource.

```
internal class MyResources
{
    // other properties etc

    internal static string SomeLabel 
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("SomeLabel", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally you will use this resource like this:

```
string label = MyResources.SomeLabel;
```

But you don't have to do this. Instead you can access the ResourceManager directly:

```
string label = MyResources.ResourceManager.GetString(m_Action);
```

Comment: i spent almost two days searching for that, if you were next to me i would kiss you